# When use ajax inside h:commandLink, FacesMessage is not displaying

Tags: ajax, jsf

In jsf. i'm using h:commandLink for adding objects in list. without selecting mandatory fields objects not added in list and showing warning message.its working fine when not using ajax 'render' inside the h:commandLink.

later i decide, i don't want to load my page. so i added ajax inside h:commandLink. but warning message not showing.Please help to fix this problem.

With ajax working:

```
<h:commandLink value="ADD" action="#{uomGroupBean.goToAddItem}" class="btn-secondary">
                  <f:ajax render="ITEM_TABLE"></f:ajax>
                  </h:commandLink>
```

Without ajax working:

```
<h:commandLink value="ADD" action="#{uomGroupBean.goToAddItem}" class="btn-secondary"/>
```

Method for adding:

```
public String goToAddItem(){
        System.out.println("calling......");
        if(uomGroup.getBaseUOM()==null){
            Util.addWarn("Please select Base UOM");
            return null;
        }

        if(uomGroup.getUomGroupItems()==null || uomGroup.getUomGroupItems().size()==0){
            uomGroup.setUomGroupItems(new ArrayList<UomGroupItem>());
        }
        uomGroup.getUomGroupItems().add(new UomGroupItem());

        return "Called";
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the `<h:messages>` or `<h:message>` tag is inside `ITEM_TABLE` block?

Comment: No.I didn't used used. that is datatable's Id.

Comment: in `f:ajax` the `render` attribute should refer to a component id in the ui.

Comment: yeah. it is referring correctly. but message is not displaying

Comment: please post the `#{uomGroupBean.goToAddItem}` code.

Comment: Please check it.question is updated

Comment: You still do not update the messages component. Therefor it won't show the messages. You need to give the messages component an id to and add that to the render attribute.

Comment: can u share how to do that. but what i have done, showing messages in bean side. without using ajax it's working fine.but when added ajax in h:commandLink  not working.